# FakeApplication does not contain the body

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have a controller written in Scala that uses an authentication trait. The trait has an isAuthenticated method like below:

```
def isAuthenticated(f: => AccountDTO => Request[AnyContent] => Result) =
Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
  Action.async {
    request => {
      Future.successful(f(user)(request))
    }
  }
}
```

In the controller, my method uses the trait method to check if the user is authenticated or not prior to doing the actual work:

```
def createFileMetadata() = isAuthenticated { user => implicit request =>
    {
    ....
    }
```

When doing a POST request (from Postman or an UI) everything works as intended, however I am facing serious problems when trying to do unit tests.

Unit tests are as follows:

```
val goodRequest = FakeRequest(POST, url).withJsonBody([a JsObject]).withHeaders((HeaderNames.AUTHORIZATION, "someMockToken"))
```

Now, if in my controller I use `request.body.asJson` I get `None`. Furthermore, if I have the `(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")` I get 400 (Bad Request) without even entering the controller method.

i also tried using `withBody()` instead of `withJsonBody()`, but with the same results. Desperately I even tried to build a request using the Java implementation `RequestBuidler()`, but with the exact same results.

Again, making a request when the app is running, works, just the unit tests have problems. Using debug I saw something strange and this may be the problem. As seen in the image below, when executing the unit test, the 'body' in the request is empty, however, the body in the rh$1 exists and is as I set it. When making a request from Postman to the application, the 'body' exists with the value sent.

[image: Debug screen]

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or a workaround) was to use call() instead of apply():

```
val result = call(filesController.createFileMetadata(), goodRequest)
```

Now everything works as intended.